# how to run renderscript on GPU in nexus 5

Tags: android, gpu, renderscript

I want to run Renderscrip on GPU in Nexus 5, but according to my test result, the renderscrip just run on CPU in nexus 5, but it can run on GPU in Nexus 10. Does anybody  know how to run the Renderscript in GPU in Nexus 5?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now you cant force `renderscript` to run on `gpu` .The decision of running the code on `cpu` and `gpu` is decided by the code at `runtime`.Its a random procedure.